# ¿Cómo alinear imágenes en galería?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola como estan? Estoy practicando en un proyecto para mi porfolio y necesito que las imagenes esten horizontalmente o una al lado de la otra y con el código como lo tengo se ven de modo vertical una debajo de la otra. Al final les adjunto una imagen de como se ve y de como quisiera que se viera

ESTE ES MI HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Tecnologías</h1>
    </div>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgbox">
    <img alt="photo 1" src="../../../assets/html.jpg" />
          </div>
<div class="content">
    </div>
    <h2>HTML</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eum, sed itaque laboriosam quae earum eos ab incidunt, facere quis rerum sunt fuga odit delectus, aspernatur sapiente atque numquam ipsam animi.</p>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgbox">
    <img alt="photo 2" src="../../../assets/css.jpeg"/>
          </div>
<div class="content">
    </div>
    <h2>CSS</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgbox">
    <img alt="photo 3" src="../../../assets/js.png" />
          </div>
<div class="content">
    </div>
    <h2>JAVASCRIPT</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgbox">
    <img alt="photo 1" src="../../../assets/angular.jpeg" />
          </div>
<div class="content">
    </div>
    <h2>ANGULAR</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgbox">
    <img alt="photo 1" src="../../../assets/bt.jpeg" />
          </div>
<div class="content">
    </div>
    <h2>BOOTSTRAP</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>
 </div>

 
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgbox">
    <img alt="photo 1" src="../../../assets/java.jpg" />
          </div>
<div class="content">
    </div>
    <h2>JAVA</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>
 </div>
    
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgbox">
    <img alt="photo 1" src="../../../assets/REACT.jpeg" />
          </div>
<div class="content">
    </div>
    <h2>REACT</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="imgbox">
    <img alt="photo 1" src="../../../assets/NODE.jpeg"/>
          </div>
<div class="content">
    </div>
    <h2>NODE JS</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Hola como estan? Estoy practicando en un proyecto para mi porfolio y necesito que las imagenes esten horizontalmente o una al lado de la otra y con el código como lo tengo se ven de modo vertical una debajo de la otra. Al final les adjunto una imagen de como se ve y de como quisiera que se viera
Y ESTE ES MI CSS

```
body{
    background: rgb(1, 0, 14);
}
h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 1160px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}
.container .box{
    position: relative;
    width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
    background: rgb(6, 56, 121);
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.container:hover .box{
    transform: rotateY(25deg);
}
.container .box:hover ~ .box{
    transform: rotateY(-25deg);
}
.container .box:hover{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) scale(1.25);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 25px 40px rgb(116, 4, 106);
}
.container .box .imgbox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container .box .imgbox:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,rgb(167, 62, 236),rgb(10, 21, 179));
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.container .box:hover .imgbox:before{
    opacity: 1;
}
.container .box .imgbox img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.container .box .content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: flex-end;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container .box .content h2{
    color: aliceblue;
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transform: translateY(200px);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.container .box:hover .content h2{
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
.container .box .content p{
    color: rgb(213, 235, 23);
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 14px;
    transform: translateY(200px);
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.container .box:hover .content p{
    transform: translateY(0px);
```

Hola como estan? Estoy practicando en un proyecto para mi porfolio y necesito que las imagenes esten horizontalmente o una al lado de la otra y con el código como lo tengo se ven de modo vertical una debajo de la otra. Al final les adjunto una imagen de como se ve y de como quisiera que se viera

}[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz intentado con **flex-direction: row;** en tu contenedor padre?

Comment: Si lo probé y nada

Comment: No lo veo aplicado... Tienes que agrupar todos tus **container** dentro de un _div_ (contenedor padre), a ese contenedor le asignas **display:flex**, y **flex-direction:row;**.

Comment: lo probe recien

Comment: Ah lo escribi mal perdon sisi ahi funciono

Comment: resuelto entonces?